# fvwm confguration

Tags: configuration

Anyone please has a fvwm configuration working with Ubuntu 16.04 and where stalonetray working properly?

[The configuration I use](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23502731/), FvwmButtons (panel, taskabar) doesn't swallow stalonetray.

The stalonetray it appear as a different mobile very little window, which is not possible to make it bigger is not part of the FvwmButtons (panel, taskabar) as I would like, and it can not be used at all.

[Fvwm configuratiton part for the panel and stalonetray](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23502789/)

[Stalonetray configuration](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23502803/)

I would like to use stalonetray to see the Laptop battery status and to have the volume icon.

For those using fvwm, what other options are to have on the FvwmButtons (panel, taskabar) the Laptop battery status and the volume icon please.

Plus if anyone knows please how to move the FvwmButtons (panel, taskabar) to be on the bottom of the screen, not on the right side.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Did adding the word Test to line 591 of your configuration fix the swallowing issue with Stalonetray?

If you want stalonetray to show a battery icon, you can `sudo apt-get install fdpowermon`, it will go in your tray and provide you with a battery icon.

For volume, if you use pulse audio, you could `sudo apt-get install pasystray`.

For the position of the tray, the geometry string controls where the FvwmButtons window will be.  So -0-0 would get you the bottom right, as opposed to your current -0+0 which is top right (line 573).  So try this for line 573:

```
*RightPanel: Geometry 120x$[vp.height]-0-0
```

Make sure you update your fvwm config to launch pasystray and fdpowermon if you want them.  For example:

```
AddToFunc StartFunction
+ I Exec exec pasystray
+ I Exec exec fdpowermon
```